# telethon database is locked

Tags: telegram, telethon

im trying to make a little mseeage sender software
here is my last code version
if anyone have thie error before and can help me
i would be happy thanks
"telethon database is locked"

```
  async def send_messages(self, api_id, api_hash, session_name, usernames, message, delay, max_messages):
        messages_sent = 0
        for username in usernames:
            if messages_sent >= max_messages:
                break  # Exit the loop when the message limit is reached

            try:
                client = TelegramClient(f'sessions/{session_name}', api_id, api_hash)
                await client.start()
                result = await client(ResolveUsernameRequest(username.strip()))
                user_id = result.peer.user_id
                await client.send_message(user_id, message)
                self.console_output.insert(tk.END, f'Successfully sent message to {username} using session {session_name}\n')
                messages_sent += 1  # Increment the messages sent count
                self.sent_usernames.add(username)  # Mark the username as sent
                await asyncio.sleep(delay)
                await client.disconnect()
            except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:

                self.console_output.insert(tk.END, f'Could not send message to {username}: {e}\n')


        session_files = [file for file in os.listdir('sessions') if file.endswith('.session')]
        if not session_files:
            self.console_output.insert(tk.END, "No session files found in the 'sessions' folder.\n")
        else:
            chunk_size = len(self.usernames) // len(session_files)
            for i, session_name in enumerate(session_files):
                start_index = i * chunk_size
                end_index = start_index + chunk_size if i < len(session_files) - 1 else len(self.usernames)
                chunk_usernames = self.usernames[start_index:end_index]

                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
                self.sending_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: loop.run_until_complete(self.send_messages(api_id, api_hash, session_name, chunk_usernames, message, delay, max_messages)))
                self.sending_thread.start()
```

im trying to make a little mseeage sender software
here is my last code version
if anyone have thie error before and can help me
i would be happy thanks
"telethon database is locked"

Answer (score 0):

[From the FAQ](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/v1.31.0/readthedocs/quick-references/faq.rst#sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked):

> An older process is still running and is using the same `'session'`
> file.
>
> This error occurs when **two or more clients use the same session**,
> that is, when you write the same session name to be used in the
> client:
>
> - You have an older process using the same session file.
> - You have two different scripts running (interactive sessions count too).
> - You have two clients in the same script running at the same time.
>
> The solution is, if you need two clients, use two sessions. If the
> problem persists and you're on Linux, you can use `fuser my.session`
> to find out the process locking the file. As a last resort, you can
> reboot your system.
>
> If you really dislike SQLite, use a different session storage. There
> is an entire section covering that at *sessions*.